# Dynamically Created HTML Element Loses Attributes On Show/Hide

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating an input that basically fakes a password input temporarily like so:

```
var fakeId = currentElement.attr("id") + "Fake";

var fakePasswordInput = $("<input>",
{
    id: fakeId,
    val: value,
    type: "text",
    class: cssClass
});

currentElement.after(fakePasswordInput);
```

My problem is when this happens:

```
        currentElement.blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).hide();
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var val = elements["#" + id];
                // have NO idea why, but it loses the CSS class AND the value.
                $("#" + id + "Fake").show();
            }
        });
```

The last line, `$("#" + id + "Fake").show();` will happily show the element, however it loses both its CSS class and the value that it had in it. To fix this, I do the following:

```
$("#" + id + "Fake").val(val).addClass(cssClass).show();
```

It's a hack, which I'm not keen on. So, why does hiding then showing a dynamically generated HTML element lose its attributes? (This happens in Chrome/FF/IE)

**EDIT**

This is all defined in a single function. The `cssClass` is declared right at the very top like so:

```
function formBlur(elements) {
    var cssClass = "default_text_input";
```

Comment: How do you get cssClass and value when creating fakePasswordInput?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var fakePasswordInput = $("<input/>",
{
    id: fakeId,
    val: value,
    type: "text",
    class: cssClass
});
```

you should probably close the input tag
 when creating it on fly using this kind of syntax

Answer (score 0):

Plase try to change the val argument to value.

```
var fakePasswordInput = $("<input/>",
{
    id: fakeId,
    value: value,
    type: "text",
    class: cssClass
});
```

The class argument seems correct. May be it is not working because of the value argument.